# Is it possible to remove Linux from dual boot without a recovery drive?

Tags: dual-boot, grub, elementary-os

I installed Elementary OS alongside Windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop, and now I want to remove it. I saw in some online forums that deleting the partitions will work, but removing *grub* is essential. But I don't have a recovery drive, so what do I do?

Comment: Re-install Windows boot loader from Windows (IIRC  you can use `bootrec` command line tool). Afterwards verify that your system boots directly to Windows (no grub). Then should be able to safely delete Linux partitions.

Comment: Is your PC running in BIOS legacy mode, or UEFI. If UEFI, you'll just have to set the default EFI target to windows10.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a Windows question ...

You can get a Windows partitioning program to fix the MBR for you, you will have to restart for that to work. EaseUS is one I have read about, never tried it ...

You can also use `bootrec.exe`, to use that, you need to be in recovery mode ... the catch is, you do not need recovery media with Windows 10 to get in there, you do need your recovery partition, though ... should be there, unless you removed that when you installed Linux ...

1. Open msconfig.exe.
2. On the "Boot" tab, check "Safe boot" and then select "Minimal".
3. Click Apply and Ok.
4. Choose to Reboot.
5. As it restarts, you will get a menu that reads: "Choose your option", here you want "Troubleshoot".
6. In "Troubleshoot" you have two options, you want "Advanced options".
7. In "Advanced options" you want "Command prompt".
8. In the command prompt, you issue the following commands:

   `bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd`

   `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`

   `bootrec.exe /fixboot`

Sources:
http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10
http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/repair-mbr-windows-10.html